# unlimited paid frontend registration according to membership type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, registration

I have a wordpress project in which i have to let the client register in my site. And the registration is paid. And there are many options of registering like: 1 person 100, and if he choose to add a partner then 80 is added and again if he wants to add a child below 18 yrs 50 added then so on. And other option is group of 5 member registration are charged 200. These are the registration requirement. I have used s2 member for this but s2 member has only membership level for registration in which for every option there need to be different registration form, but i need to register the members stated above in one form. So how can i do this with wordpress. Could someone kind enough to help me out its been a headache for me and i have to solve this in any manner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would either have to try and show us where you are stuck after you researched it yourself or hire a developer.

Comment: @RonniSkansing i have added registration levels prices with combining the registration requirement like single members, with partner etc and set up different registration forms for each of them but the clients want to have only single registration form with various members type i have discussed earlier in the question.

Comment: Are just installing plugins/themes and charging customers? Or do you  have some code with a real problem we can help you with?

Comment: @RonniSkansing I am now stuck in how to get that functionality either i can get it with the s2member plugin or i have to custom code it for the requirement i want, if it was php then it was easy but as it is wordpress it is difficult for me to know how to get this.

Comment: Wordpress is written with PHP (in a very old bad fashion) and the plugins/themes are php as well. Sorry but it sounds like you have no idea what you are really doing, which makes it hard to help you. Next time you hit a wall, what will you do? Open a new question? Also you already have a question about this which has been closed "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904997/paid-front-end-user-registration-in-wordpress".

Comment: @RonniSkansing yeah i know that wordpress is written in php but you must also have know that its not core php or framework and it has its own coding convention which needs to be learned too besides php, so i think you didn't understand my problem. By the way thanks for viewing it and commenting.